# Tensorflow: weights seem random after restoring model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am having difficulty correctly saving and then restoring a tensorflow model.  Specifically, I have a script (script #1) that trains a model using some data and then tests it on that same data. (I know you would never do that in real life, but for the purposes of my problem, it doesn't matter). Script #2 is supposed to load the saved model and then predict on the same data in which the model was trained. The problem is that I get different predictions when performing inference in script #1 versus script #2.

In script #1:

```
sess, softmax_probabilities = train_model(data, labels, full_model_filename) # train model
p = [x[1] for x in softmax_probabilities.eval({data_placeholder: data, label_placeholder: labels, dropout_keep_proportion_placeholder: 1.0}, session=sess)] # test model on same data
```

Here, the values in variable "p" make sense, and everything is good.

Inside train_model is this code for saving the model:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, model_filename)
```

In script #2, I have the following:

```
loaded_graph = tf.Graph()
with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(args.model_meta_filename)
    new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

    softmax_probabilities = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax_probabilities:0')
    data_placeholder = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('data_placeholder:0')
    dropout_keep_proportion_placeholder = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('dropout_keep_proportion_placeholder:0')

    p = [x[1] for x in softmax_probabilities.eval({data_placeholder: data, dropout_keep_proportion_placeholder: 1.0})]

    print(p)
```

This time, the values in variable "p" are almost all very close to 0.5.  So, it's as if the loaded model has random weights. There must be something I'm doing wrong with respect to loading the model, but I can't figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I read several other threads on Stack Overflow where  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) was accidentally run after loading the model, thereby overwriting the weights, but I haven't done that here.)

Again, thank you so much for any help, and let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the line of code:

```
new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

With:

```
new_saver.restore(sess, args.model_meta_filename.replace(".meta", ""))
```

To clarify, `args.model_meta_filename` is the name of the saved file that ends in .meta.

Comment: Did they both give you the same output? 
like: INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from storedsess.ckpt

Cause I have the same problem but your solution didn't solve my problem so I was wondering if it was a problem of loading the wrong file in your case